# Azure -- Ignoring domain when logging in?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365

I'm using Azure's SSO service, and every time a user wants to login in to their Office 365 portal, they have to enter their whole username and their domain?

Is it possible to create a website so that Azure knows what domain we are so the users don't have to type in their domain? This is an issue for us because their actual email and Active Directory usernames are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

You van specify a domain hint, which sends users to the correct azure login page: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/02/11/using-azure-ad-to-land-users-on-their-custom-login-page-from-within-your-app/